# PutAsync Doesn't Send Message Body

Tags: c#, json, uwp, put, dotnet-httpclient

I am just trying to send a body with JSON to the server.

This is my code.

```
var data = await SerializationAdapter.SerializeAsync<TBody>(body);
var bodyString = Encoding.GetString(data);
var length = bodyString.Length;
var stringContent = new StringContent(bodyString, Encoding, contentType);

stringContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);

stringContent.Headers.ContentLength = length;

result = await _HttpClient.PutAsync(queryString, stringContent);
```

It works fine when I POST, but PUT doesn't send any body. I checked the Request in Fiddler, and nothing was there. I debugged this code and I can see that `bodyString` is a valid, serializable JSON string, but it is not being passed to the server.

**Why is there no body in the request?**

Comment: You're saying this _exact_ code works fine if you use `PostAsync` instead of `PutAsync`? That would be very strange, makes me wonder if it's a server-side issue. Is the server code yours, and can you post a snippet of it showing how you're verifying there's no body?

Comment: It's not server side code, it's UWP. The title of the thread included UWP, but someone edited that out for some unknown reason. The library is in .NET Standard 2.0. I'm not at my computer right now but I will go home and confirm that answers to your questions with screenshots etc.

Comment: As a workaround, have you tried manually creating a `HttpRequestMessage` and using `SendAsync`? As this is using more generic code, it might bypass the bug.

Comment: No I haven't. I will try it.

Comment: This is the code I was using before: https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net/src/b292260aeecc78825d3d80f549519bb99c575591/Shared/src/RESTClient.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: I'm trying to migrate this code to use HttpClient. The old code works fine.

Comment: @RB , this is not a bug in the UWP HttpClient. I misread the results. That was my bad. I'm still investigating.

Comment: To answer @ToddMenier I'm not actually sure now that the Post version is doing anything different. I'm am investigating to see what is going on. All I can say is that the code above does not send any body in the request. My only question is why it does not.

Comment: Just for confirm, the above code is  inside a .Net standard  library and your UWP app reference it , right?

Comment: Yes. I think I have fixed the problem, and I think I have documented this problem all wrong. I think this is a non-issue. I will update when this is 100% worked out.

Comment: Did you get this issue worked out? I too have experienced this and even hard-coded a JSON string and it still wasn't getting sent and unfortunately, I cannot breakpoint inside of the putasync method. @MelbourneDeveloper